# Disabling the scheduler to reduce the cpu time on spinlock

Tags: linux, scheduler, kvm, spinlock

In linux, in kvm environment, when a process in VM locks on some resource and is pre-empted, other processes of VM, which need that locked resource would spend time on spinlock. And the process would unlock the resource when it's allotted the PROCESSOR.

I would like to disable the scheduler from pre-emptying, until the process unlocks the resource. And this would reduce the cpu-time on spinlock.

How to achieve the above??  i.e.

1. How to findout if a process in VM has locked on some resource?
2. Then how
   to inform scheduler to not to pre-empt the process until the resource is unlocked?

correct me if am wrong anywhere..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Basilevs : I meant pre-empt..

Answer (score 0):

Use spinlock_irq_save() call. It disables interrupts and preempting and locks a spinlock atomically.
See http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spinlocks.txt for use cases.